# Placement New Operator

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;    

int main() {
    int buf[2];
    int *p=new (buf) int(2);
    int *q=new (buf+1) int(6);
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        cout<<buf[i]<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying placement new operator with the following example. For the above code I get the output as:

```
trial.cpp:7:20: warning: placement new constructing an object of type 'int' and size '4' in a region of type 'int [2]' and size '0' [-Wplacement-new=]
     int *q=new (buf+1) int(6);
2 6
```

Why am I getting a warning for *q ? From my understanding p and q are 2 pointers pointing to 2 different blocks in buf array. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Looks like your static analysis tool is a bit too aggressive. Does the warning go away if you make the conversion explicit with `&buf[1]` instead?

Comment: Is it even allowed to use placement new on array? Array creates its own objects

Comment: @Yksisarvinen You can replace the array elements with new ones.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes the warning goes away on using &buf[1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a GCC bug affecting versions 8 to 10 and fixed in 11, see [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96511).

The code is fine, the warning a false-positive.